# Negative time interval

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to add the GMT hours to the zulu departure time to convert to the local time. However, I am facing with some issue with negative interval hours in my first comment and "interval GMT hour" in my second comment. Appreciate your kind advice.

```
SELECT

a.depart_gateway,
a.depart_tmpstp,

/*
CASE
WHEN a.depart_gateway IN ('ICN','NRT','KIX') THEN INTERVAL '9' HOUR
WHEN a.depart_gateway IN ('MEM') THEN INTERVAL '-2' HOUR
END AS GMT,

a.depart_tmpstp + GMT as local_depart_tmpst
*/

/*
CASE
WHEN a.depart_gateway IN ('ICN','NRT','KIX') THEN 9
WHEN a.depart_gateway IN ('MEM') THEN -2
END AS GMT,

a.depart_tmpstp + INTERVAL GMT HOUR as local_depart_tmpst
*/

FROM flight.a
```

Comment: The new GMT column isn't available yet. Either have a sub-query, or repeat the case expression.

Comment: Note, it's a scoping issue, and has nothing to to with negative intervals.

Comment: @jarlh May I know how should the sub-query be? or where should I place the case expression?

Comment: @jarlh: It's not a scoping issue, Teradata allows using an alias. Remove the minus from the literal, either `INTERVAL -'2' HOUR` or `-INTERVAL '2' HOUR`

Comment: a.depart_tmpstp + "same case"

Comment: @dnoeth, I see, thanks!

Comment: And for the 2nd CASE: `GMT * INTERVAL '1' HOUR` or better `a.depart_tmpstp AT GMT`

Comment: Too bad different products and standards can't do this the same way. ANSI SQL says `INTERVAL '-2'`, ISO8601 accepts both `INTERVAL '-2'` and `INTERVAL -'2'`...

Comment: @jarlh: But ANSI is supposed to be the same a ISO, strange.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks for the advice! GMT * INTERVAL '1' HOUR works!

Comment: It works, but `a.depart_tmpstp AT GMT` is shorter :-)

Comment: No, AT can be used with both an integer or an interval, but it will result in a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, if depart_tmpstp has no time zone, you might keep your existing calculation.

Comment: @dnoeth a.depart_tmpstp AT GMT also works but may I know whats the function of "AT"  , how does it know that GMT is in HOUR. I tried googling "AT" in SQL but couldnt find any information.

Comment: @dnoeth So "AT" is a special function to add timezone into timestamp. Got it! Thanks!

Comment: `AT` is used to change the time zone, e.g. `Current_Timestamp AT 'europe western'`, see https://docs.teradata.com/reader/w19R4KsuHIiEqyxz0WYfgA/CCe6s05~ILx7XW7fhKSQ5Q